# Alembic try to drop table after create table instead of before

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I'm trying to migrate with Alembic.

Env.py :

```html
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

import sys
import os

sys.path.insert(0, os.getcwd())
print(sys.path)
from appli.Base import Base

print(Base.metadata.sorted_tables)


# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata
target_metadata = Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline():
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online():
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

alembic.ini :

```html
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic

# template used to generate migration files
# file_template = %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# timezone to use when rendering the date
# within the migration file as well as the filename.
# string value is passed to dateutil.tz.gettz()
# leave blank for localtime
# timezone =

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
# truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; this defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar %(here)s/bat alembic/versions

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

sqlalchemy.url = mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/test_migration


[post_write_hooks]
# post_write_hooks defines scripts or Python functions that are run
# on newly generated revision scripts.  See the documentation for further
# detail and examples

# format using "black" - use the console_scripts runner, against the "black" entrypoint
# hooks=black
# black.type=console_scripts
# black.entrypoint=black
# black.options=-l 79

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

I initialize the database with that in first :

```html
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, UniqueConstraint

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root@localhost/test_migration')

#The axis on which the tests are executed
class AXIS(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Axis'
    id_axis        = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name_axis      = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
```

And I get that in the version upgrade. Everything is right.

```html
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('Axis',
    sa.Column('id_axis', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name_axis', sa.String(length=10), nullable=False),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id_axis')
    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

Next i add a column named test to my table named axis to test the migration :

```html
#The axis on which the tests are executed
class AXIS(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Axis'
    id_axis        = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    name_axis      = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
    test           = Column(String(10), nullable=False)
```

Then we get a new version file:

```html
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('Axis',
    sa.Column('id_axis', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('name_axis', sa.String(length=10), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('test', sa.String(length=10), nullable=False),
    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id_axis')
    )
    op.drop_table('axis')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###
```

But I noticed that alembic first tried to create the tables (already existing) and then tried to delete them. For the upgrade to work, you must move the drop before the create.

Why is the drop after the create? If it's normal, please explain it to me. If it's not normal, what could be the source of my error?

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Did you change the table's name from `axis` to `Axis`?

Comment: No i don't. I don't know why alembic try to drop "axis" and not "Axis"

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem, you can change the `__tablename__ = 'Axis'` to `__tablename__ = 'axis'`. It works at least, but I don't know how to work with the Upper table name

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32934852)